# Ruby - Threads and Dir[] arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, multithreading

I have built a ruby script that creates folders, moves a file into that new folder and then invokes a `system()` call to trigger FFMPEG. I have now turned this into 4 threads so that I can do 4 concurrent transcodes at a time.

Here is an example with 2 threads (minus folder structure creation and file move functions):

```
def transcode_process_1

 Dir["path/file/source/*.mxf"].each do |f|

   random_folder = #code for random folder creation

   file_move = #code to move .mxf file to random_folder for processing

   system("FFMPEG -i #{random_folder} command 2> /path/file/#{random_filename}.txt")

   sleep(2)

 end
end

def transcode_process_2

 sleep(3)

 Dir["path/file/source/*.mxf"].each do |f|

   random_folder = #code for random folder creation

   file_move = #code to move .mxf file to random_folder for processing

   system("FFMPEG -i #{random_folder} command 2> /path/file/#{random_filename}.txt")

   sleep(4)

 end
end

transcode_thread_1 = Thread.new{transcode_process_1()}
transcode_thread_2 = Thread.new{transcode_process_2()}

transcode_thread_1.join
transcode_thread_2.join
```

This iterates through the Dir "path/file/source/" and processes any .mxf files it finds. The issue I am having is that when both threads are running they are adding the same files into the array. This results in FFMPEG stating it cannot locate the file (this is because another thread has processed it and moved it to the temp folder) and creating superfluous folders and log files, basically just making it messy.

My question is how would I go about making sure `transcode_thread_2` does not process files that `transcode_thread_1` has added to it array? Is there a way I can get the function to check that the file in the array is still exists? If it does then carry out the process, if not move on to the next file?

Thanks

Comment: Try using a [queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) to hold the list of files, and share that between the threads

Comment: Can't you just split files into 2-3-4 arrays and then process them in 2-3-4 threads, so they don't overlap?

Comment: Simplest case, you could get the function to test `if File.exist?(f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this, but I would consider the second way to be superior.

## 1 - Check if the file exists before proceeding

Simply add a `File.exist?(f)` check to your code:

```
def transcode_process_1
    Dir["path/file/source/*.mxf"].each do |f|
        next if !File.exist?(f)
        ..carry on as normal..
```

## 2 - Use a Queue (part of the Threads package)

You can use a Queue, which is accessible by all threads. This simplifies things in a number of ways

1. Central list of items to process
2. Accessible by all threads, you can spawn as many threads as you can handle
3. Removes multiple versions of the same code and those [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) sleep values

Something along the lines of:

```
require 'thread'

total_threads = 2 # Or however cores you have    

transcode_queue = Queue.new
transcode_queue << Dir["path/file/source/*.mxf"]

def transcode_process(queue)
    while !queue.empty?
        file = queue.pop # Process this file

        random_folder = '' #code for random folder creation
        random_filename = '' # this was missing from your example

        file_move = '' #code to move .mxf file to random_folder for processing

        system("FFMPEG -i #{random_folder} command 2> /path/file/#{random_filename}.txt")
    end
end

(1..total_threads).each {
    Thread.new { transcode_process(transcode_queue) }
}
```

You don't really need to `sleep()` as there should be no race condition anymore having accessed the queue, and you've shared the same code for each new thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this! As you can tell I am a Ruby / stackoverflow noob. I will give method 2 a try tonight.

Comment: I went with option 1 in the end and it works perfectly. I really like the idea of method 2 but I don't understand to I could get it to start the transcoding process? More research is needed. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the arrays you are talking about, but here is how you can sort this out with a common accumulator which keeps track of processed data:

```
acc = []

t1 = Thread.new do
  a1 = []
  (1..10).each do |i|
    unless acc.include?(i)
      acc << i
      a1 << i
      p "a1 << #{i}"
    end
  end
  p "a1 = #{a1}"
end

t2 = Thread.new do
  a2 = []
  (1..10).each do |i|
    unless acc.include?(i)
      acc << i
      a2 << i
      p "a2 << #{i}"
    end
  end
  p "a2 = #{a2}"
end

t1.join
t2.join
```